# update a column with / in mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to update a column contains below value:

```
\\localhost\db\kkk\086018\ss\DocA\1_216925.jpg
```

with

```
\\localhost\db\kkk\086018\dd\DocA\1_216925.jpg
```

by using below C# code:

```
string str = "update my_document " +
                                "set path = replace (path,'" + fromFolder + "','" + toFolder + "')" +
                                "where doc_id in( select doc_id from patient_document where folder_id='" + id + "')";
            str.Replace("\\", "\\\\");
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ECModel.Instance.ConnString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, conn))
                {   
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
}
```

what I observe that path submitting correctly to mysql but it wont reflect since between C# application and mysql, all the \\ convert to \ .

Would you mind advice me how to solve my issue?

- I used @ in front of my str also but that solution also didn't work.

** also I notice when I run my update statement with \\\\ it is working fine.

Comment: You need to figure out how to use placeholder values for your data instead of just smashing it in with concatenation. That's the source of a whole legion of problems, not the least of which is [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @tadman god save you. my problem solved by using parameter. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

To try to keep this simple, I think the problem you're having is you effectively need both the "@" and the escape values. Try something like this. It worked for me. I made some assumptions on the data structures, and tested this on SQL Server, not MySQL, but I think the concept is sound and I reverted the code back to the MySQL client for you.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program program = new Program();
        program.updateTable("1", @"\\share\from\path", @"\\share\to\path");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void updateTable(string id, string fromFolder, string toFolder)
    {
        string str = @"update my_document " +
                    "set path = replace (path,'" + fromFolder + "','" + toFolder + "')" +
                    "where doc_id in( select doc_id from patient_document where folder_id='" + id + "')";

        str.Replace("\\", "\\\\");

        Console.WriteLine(str);

        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ECModel.Instance.ConnString))
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the same code . but it didn't . i changed to use by parameter as  @tadman advised.

Comment: I would agree that the parameter approach is better for a host of reasons.